# SFDX Setting Default Org "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost" problem

Tags: salesforcedx

When I try to set a default org in vscode, errors which is shown below picture returns. I think it is related with host file but I couldn't find solution. How can I solve this?

```
    tarting SFDX: Authorize an Org

12:50:41.62 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias bo --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost' }
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost' }
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'localhost' }
12:50:41.498 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias bo --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 0
```

Comment: try restarting?

Comment: What operating system? What's happening is that the `sfdx` CLI tries to start a web server on `localhost`, which should be your own computer,  for the OAuth callback when you use the `force:auth:web:login` command. But it's somehow not able to find it. Have you done some configuration on your machine that would direct `localhost` elsewhere?

Comment: Try disabling the proxy used for masking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, this is due to your machine is unable to resolve the localhost dns mapping. You need to do the following to fix this issue:

type this in your terminal

```
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

If this returns nothing you need to add the following lines to it and if it has some info in the file make sure it matches with the below info:

> ```
> 127.0.0.1       localhost
> ::1     localhost
> 255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
> ```

Comment: Mohammed - thanks for the answer. Can you edit it to include your operating system? I believe your solution would be applicable to Linux and probably macOS, but isn't applicable to Windows. Halil never said whas OS was referenced in the question, so having it in the answer would be helpful.

Comment: Can confirm macOS (and Linux). For Win the file you need to edit is `Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` IIRC.

Comment: Hi I can see the following information returned 127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost. But still getting the same error.