# Not able to Authorize an Org with VS CODE

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the following command in terminal: sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias org1 --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
2. Then I am redirected to my salesforce org. I enter the username and password. It navigates to the following URL: http://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect?code=aPrxxWbemCeRRVGtTbQ_rFrxBRMkjctFrGHu3gxj0lM2iahw2P0MG4Fjt_HwgCiAYEQPTfRVog%3D%3D&state=e62b3ab21b50

Error Message  on Terminal :
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26) {
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'localhost'
}

Comment: is domain enabled org? if yes use actual domain url instead of login.salesforce.com.

Comment: can you try to update VScode plugin? It seems due to the sfdx CLI update, that moved sfdx force:auth:weblogin to sfdx auth:web:login

Comment: Check (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264343/sfdx-setting-default-org-getaddrinfo-enotfound-localhost-problem)

Comment: Tired sfdx auth:web:login the issue is still there.

Comment: @Vinay: I tried the options available in the link. I already have that configuration

Comment: Can you try using sfdx auth:web:login --setalias org1 --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername.   Salesforce CLI latest version has issues (https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/811)